# String to 2D Array with streams [Java 8]

Tags: java, arrays, java-8, java-stream

I am currently learning how to do streams, while doing some assignments for fun (Advent of code). While I know how how to do it with temporary arrays, I do not know the correct syntax for streams or if it is even possible to do it in one line.

```
public class M3 {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s = "104\t240\t147\t246\t123\t175\t372\t71\t116\t230\t260\t118\t202\t270\t277\t292\n" +
            "740\t755\t135\t205\t429\t822\t844\t90\t828\t115\t440\t805\t526\t91\t519\t373\n" +
            "1630\t991\t1471\t1294\t52\t1566\t50\t1508\t1367\t1489\t55\t547\t342\t512\t323\t51\n" +
            "1356\t178\t1705\t119\t1609\t1409\t245\t292\t1434\t694\t405\t1692\t247\t193\t1482\t1407\n" +
            "2235\t3321\t3647\t212\t1402\t3711\t3641\t1287\t2725\t692\t1235\t3100\t123\t144\t104\t101\n" +
            "1306\t1224\t1238\t186\t751\t734\t1204\t1275\t366\t149\t1114\t166\t1118\t239\t153\t943\n" +
            "132\t1547\t1564\t512\t2643\t2376\t2324\t2159\t1658\t107\t1604\t145\t2407\t131\t2073\t1878\n" +
            "1845\t91\t1662\t108\t92\t1706\t1815\t1797\t1728\t1150\t1576\t83\t97\t547\t1267\t261\n" +
            "78\t558\t419\t435\t565\t107\t638\t173\t93\t580\t338\t52\t633\t256\t377\t73\n" +
            "1143\t3516\t4205\t3523\t148\t401\t3996\t3588\t300\t1117\t2915\t1649\t135\t134\t182\t267\n" +
            "156\t2760\t1816\t2442\t2985\t990\t2598\t1273\t167\t821\t138\t141\t2761\t2399\t1330\t1276\n" +
            "3746\t3979\t2989\t161\t4554\t156\t3359\t173\t3319\t192\t3707\t264\t762\t2672\t4423\t2924\n" +
            "3098\t4309\t4971\t5439\t131\t171\t5544\t595\t154\t571\t4399\t4294\t160\t6201\t4329\t5244\n" +
            "728\t249\t1728\t305\t2407\t239\t691\t2241\t2545\t1543\t55\t2303\t1020\t753\t193\t1638\n" +
            "260\t352\t190\t877\t118\t77\t1065\t1105\t1085\t1032\t71\t87\t851\t56\t1161\t667\n" +
            "1763\t464\t182\t1932\t1209\t640\t545\t931\t1979\t197\t1774\t174\t2074\t1800\t939\t161";

    int[][] iArr = Arrays.stream(s.split("\n")).map(String[]::String.split("\t"));
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct syntax is this:

```
int[][] iArr = Arrays.stream(s.split("\n")).map(r
        -> // It transforms a String 'r' into a int[]
        Arrays.stream(r.split("\t")).mapToInt(Integer::parseInt).toArray()
// It transforms a Stream of int[] into int [][]
).toArray(int[][]::new);

System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(iArr));//Print your result
```